# Question about a strange parameter type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the C++ reference documentation on [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

The following code works fine for me:

```cpp
class conststr
{
    const char* p;
    std::size_t sz;
public:
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]): p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const {
        return n < sz ? p[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
};

constexpr std::size_t countlower(conststr s) {
    std::size_t c = 0;
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < s.size(); ++n) {
        if ('a' <= s[n] && s[n] <= 'z') {
            ++c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
static_assert(countlower("Hello World") == 8);
```

My question is, how does `"Hello World"` initialized the following strange parameter list to deduct `N`?

```cpp
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]): p(a), sz(N - 1) {}
```

Comment: Is "const char(&a)[N]" a reference to an array of N element?

Comment: This is not a strange parameter (it is a reference to a "C" style array) `N`  will be deduced from the compile time length of the string literal. However it will also count the trailing `\0` (that's why you see `N-1` for  the size)

Comment: Type of `"Hello World"` is `const char[12]`, reference on that type is written as `const char (&)[12]`.

Comment: @CPW "*Is `const char(&a)[N]` a reference to an array of N element?*" - yes, it is. And a string literal is such an array.